# Can a MCP4361 digipot have a resistance of 0?

Tags: digital-potentiometer

I would like to use an MCP4361 digipot as an adjustable voltage divider with Pin A being 5V, B being ground, and W being Vout. I need the wiper voltage to span the full voltage range, including 0 and 5V.
Is this possible? Thanks.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22233a.pdf

Comment: You need to provide a link to the datasheet for the MCP4361.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the answer. Yes it can, the datasheet says this part has "Zero Scale to Full Scale Wiper operation"

Comment: Don't forget to account for the Wiper Resistance (datasheet, pg.5) if it's relevant in your application.

Comment: There will **always** be some MOSFET resistance in the path. Always. Some ohms or tens of ohms or hundreds of ohms. Always.  MOSFET channels have resistance, and that is how the switching is provided.